# How to specify date format with XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler using SpringBatch?

Tags: java, spring-batch, cell

I have troubles with the method `org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler.cell(String var1, String var2, XSSFComment var3)` regarding the var2 attribute. I'm using Spring-Batch with which I parse an `.xlsx` file with some dates in it. In the `.xlsx` file, dates are given in format `DD/MM/YYYY`, however once I reach the method given above, the var2 attribute reads `MM/DD/YY`.

I don't understand how this method is called so I don't know how to specify the date format to keep the full year value `YYYY` instead of the short format value `YY`.

This causes me trouble elsewhere as the year 2039 and up are converted to 39 and up which get later interpreted as 1939 and up.

Thank you for any help with this issue.

I figure the subsequent problem is related to the year 2038 problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). As the current definition of date relies on the binary number of seconds since the 1st of january 1970 given on 32 bits, the maximum value corresponds to the date 19th January 2038. So I guess that the subsequent methods (org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(String var1)) only expects years up to 2038 when given only two digits (YY) although there exists an attribute iDefaultYear which value is 2000. I hope that by giving it the full year, it will work as expected.

expected : `01/01/2039 -> 01/01/2039 -> 01/01/2039`
actual : `01/01/2039 -> 01/01/39 -> 01/01/1939`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think the problem comes from how excel stores dates. I have solved my issue by formatting the cell to text value and everything works fine. So I guess that excel stores short date format (YY) even though I wrote the long date format (YYYY). So when I parse the file later on, I read YY which then causes the troubles I have.